# Match each item in list to a string

Tags: ansible, yaml

Within my playbook, I've created a task that must match each string in a list, to a string.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    words: ["Today", "lovely"]

- name: Joe's Statement
  set_fact:
    statement: "Today is a very nice day"

- name: Validate Joe's Statement
  assert:
    that:
      - statement is search "{{ item }}"
    fail_msg: "FAILED"
    success_msg: "PASSED"
  loop:
    - "{{ words }}"
```

For a successful case I want my task to match each item in the list `words` to the string in `statement`. Although, my task `Validate Joe's Statement` does not work, the outcome should be a `FAILED` because `Today` is in the statement but `lovely` is not.

Comment: You are creating yourself a list of list with your loop as it is currently written. You want `loop: "{{ words }}"`, rather. (Also, you do have a typo in the `assert` module missing the **r**).

Comment: wow, that did the trick. Thank you so much for the speedy response!

Answer (score 2):

Although your issue lies in the fact that you are creating yourself a list of list in your loop parameter:

```yaml
loop:
  - "{{ words }}"
```

And that a quick fix could be to write your loop as

```yaml
loop: "{{ words }}"
```

---

There are solutions, that could declutter your output, without a loop, here, for example, the *[`select` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select)* can help you apply a test on each element of a list.
From that filter, you can even draft a better failure message, listing the end user all elements not present in the statement.

Given:

```yaml
- assert:
    that: missing_words | length == 0
    fail_msg: |-
      List of words from `{{ words }}` not found
      in the statement `{{ statement }}`: {{ missing_words }}
  vars:
    missing_words: "{{ words | difference(words | select('in', statement)) }}"
    words:
      - "Today"
      - "lovely"
    statement: "Today is a very nice day"
```

The task would yield:

```yaml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: missing_words | length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: |-
    List of words from `['Today', 'lovely']` not found
    in the statement `Today is a very nice day`: ['lovely']
```